# I need default configuration for apache 2.4

Tags: apache, configuration

I don't have default configuration files for apache2.4, because I accidentally replaced the configuration with old apache 2.2, and it's not compatible and make me can't start apache2 server. I've googled around but can't find complete basic apache2.4 configuration.

Thanks

Comment: And why can't you download/install it again (or install it on e.g. a Virtual Machine) and take the default config from there?

Comment: because it will take my precious bandwith. 3rd country problem.